# how to fix node-sass "not yet support your current environment" error on Linux

Tags: node.js, sass, node-sass

When running `npx grunt` on a system with recent enough `nodejs`, the build errors out with:

```
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (72)
>> For more information on which environments are supported please see:
>> https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.11.0
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

When run as `npx grunt --force`, it says:

```
$ npx grunt --force
/usr/bin/node: bad option: --force
```

How to fix the build?

P.S. System is ArchLinux, native nodejs version is `12.9.1-1`. Sorry, I'm not a javascript developer -- I just need to build this external thing without issues. The same repository used to build just fine. I **did** clean up all caches during testing it, but it doesn't help. Running "npm install" doesn't fix the error either.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrading `package.json` / `node-sass` to latest version (`4.12.0`?) might help.

The official release notes for this version mention "Node 12 support" as well: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.12.0